# Why does a integer, after put into an array, change values?

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, int

SOLVED IT

I've written a program that loads Strings after an equal sign, and has it count how many times its done this. After counting, I tell it to tell me how large the int is. The value I'm looking for is 3, and it tells me, 3. I then change it to an String, the value stays three. Then, I put it into an 4d array, and It tells me the value is 2. What happened?

The Code:

```
                   int times=0;
                   else if (list.equals("Weapon")) {//If the word weapon is before the = 
                        weapon = value; //take the string after the = and put it into String weapon
                        troopStats[times][1][weaponTimes][0] = weapon;
                        weaponTimes++;
                        System.out.println(weaponTimes+"weapontimes"+times);
                    }

                        weaponTimesStr = Integer.toString(weaponTimes);
                        System.out.println(weaponTimesStr+"string");
                        troopStats[times][1][0][1] = weaponTimesStr;
                        System.out.println(troopStats[times][1][0][1]+"InArray");
                        times++
                        //loops
```

The Output:

```
3weapontimes    //Counted the equals sign 3 times, Note that this is from the part of the 
                 omitted code
3string         // Changed the integer to a string and got 3
2InArray        // Put it into an array, and got 2 back
```

What Is going on?

(I know that I could just add 1 to the value, but I want to use this code for a unknown number of things later on)

To help, I've posted the entire code:

```
public class TroopLoader {
    static String[][][][] troopStats;
    static int times = 0;
    static int weaponTimes = 0;
    static int armorTimes = 0;
    static int animalTimes = 0;
    static String weaponTimesStr;
    static String armorTimesStr;
    static String animalTimesStr;
    static String troop;
    static String weapon;
    static String armor;
    static String animal;
    static String speed;
    static int total = 0;

    /*
     * [][][]
     * 
     * [total number of troops (total)]
     * 
     * [stats] 0= name 1= weapon 2= armor 3= animal 4= speed
     * 
     * [different things within stat]
     */

    public void readTroop() {

        File file = new File("resources/objects/troops.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            // repeat until all lines is read
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer troops = new StringTokenizer(text, "=");
                if (troops.countTokens() == 2) {
                    String list = troops.nextToken();

                    if (list.equals("Troop")) {
                        total++;
                    }

                    else {

                    }
                } else {

                }

            }
            troopStats = new String[total][5][10][2];

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        File file2 = new File("resources/objects/troops.txt");
        BufferedReader reader2 = null;

        try {
            reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
            String text = null;

            // repeat until all lines is read
            while ((text = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer troops = new StringTokenizer(text, "=");
                if (troops.countTokens() == 2) {
                    String list = troops.nextToken();
                    String value = troops.nextToken();

                    if (list.equals("Troop")) {
                        troop = value;

                        troopStats[times][0][0][0] = troop;
                    }

                    else if (list.equals("Weapon")) {
                        weapon = value;
                        troopStats[times][1][weaponTimes][0] = weapon;
                        weaponTimes++;
                        System.out.println(weaponTimes+"weapontimes"+times);
                    }

                    else if (list.equals("Armor")) {

                        armor = value;

                        troopStats[times][2][armorTimes][0] = armor;
                        armorTimes++;
                    }

                    else if (list.equals("Animal")) {

                        animal = value;

                        troopStats[times][3][animalTimes][0] = animal;
                        animalTimes++;
                    }

                    else if (list.equals("Speed")) {

                        speed = value;

                        troopStats[times][4][0][0] = speed;

                    }

                    else if (list.equals("Done")) {
                        weaponTimesStr = Integer.toString(weaponTimes);
                        System.out.println(weaponTimesStr+"string");
                        armorTimesStr = Integer.toString(armorTimes);
                        animalTimesStr = Integer.toString(animalTimes);
                        troopStats[times][1][0][1] = weaponTimesStr;
                        troopStats[times][1][0][1] = armorTimesStr;
                        troopStats[times][1][0][1] = animalTimesStr;
                        System.out.println(troopStats[times][1][0][1]+"InArray"+times);
                        times++;
                        troop = "";
                        weapon = "";
                        armor = "";
                        animal = "";
                        speed = "";
                        weaponTimes = 0;
                        armorTimes = 0;
                        animalTimes = 0;

                    }

                    else {

                    }

                } else {

                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if (reader2 != null) {
                    reader2.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the earlier part of the code, I had the program store a value in the location on the array with the weaponTimes variable, not storing the weaponTimes variable. My mistake, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that `times` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Can you show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Are `weaponTimesString` and `weaponTimesStr` the same? Can `times` change between line 3 & 4 (accessed by another thread)?

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger. At which line does this change occur?

Comment: I've tested times, and I'm fairly sure that it isn't a problem. (Its only the values for troopStats[0][1][0][1], the one that Is outputted, that is incorrect.)

Comment: You assign `weaponTimesString` but you use `weaponTimesStr`. Is it a copy-paste typo in the question? or is it in the code as well? [I doubt it is the issue anyway, thus it is only a comment - not an answer]

Comment: @amit typo, sorry, changing right now.

Comment: @assylias, I've not created any other threads, but if it helps, everything (all variables) are Class Variables.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not exactly a good programer, and so, I don't know how to use a debugger.

Comment: @Russell your IDE most likely enables you to insert a breakpoint and to run you program step by step so you can check the value of your variables at each line of code.

Comment: I've used System.out.println() for that...

Comment: println is fine if you know what values to print on what lines. The debugger is useful if you don't want to change the code and you don't know what is going wrong or where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with what you posted and it prints what you would expect:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][][][] troopStats = new String[4][4][4][4];
    int times = 2;
    int weaponTimes = 3;
    String weaponTimesStr = Integer.toString(weaponTimes);
    System.out.println(weaponTimesStr + "string"); //prints 3string
    troopStats[times][1][0][1] = weaponTimesStr;
    System.out.println(troopStats[times][1][0][1] + "InArray"); //prints 3InArray
}
```

So the problem is most likely something/somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep working on it. Oh and by the way, times=0 at the broken point.

Answer (score 3):

The following:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][][][] troopStats = new String[2][2][2][2];
    String weaponTimesStr = Integer.toString(3);
    System.out.println(weaponTimesStr+"string");
    troopStats[0][1][0][1] = weaponTimesStr;
    // You said in a comment that 'times' is equal to 0 in this case so have subbed that in
    System.out.println(troopStats[0][1][0][1]+"InArray");
  }
}
```

Gives me the expected output:

```
3string
3InArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I've wasted your time, my mistake was because I stored values in the array using the values of weaponTimes, and not storing weaponTimes in the array.

```
troopStats[times][1][weaponTimes][0] = weapon;
```

That was the mistake.